# Form Post Not working While Submission

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Whenever I try to post my form I get the following error:

> An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new ContactMessage());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ContactMessage post)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save to Database
            using (var db=new ContactMVC.Data.ContactDatabase())
            {
                post.DateSent = DateTime.Now;

                db.ContactMessages.Add(post);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            //redirect
            TempData["ContactMessage"] = post;
            return RedirectToAction("SucessfulMessage");
        }
        return View(post);
    }

    public ActionResult SucessfulMessage()
    {
        var message = (ContactMessage)TempData["ContactMessage"];
        return View(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can show us the inner exception?

Comment: Did you check the connection string and inner exception as the error says?

Comment: @alisabzevari what inner exception ?

Comment: @Zabavsky where can I check connection string and inner exceptions ?

Comment: When you application in visual studio throws an error you can click on exception details and check the inner exception field.

Comment: it says "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string." @alisabzevari

Comment: Message: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

Comment: Show us your connectionstring from web.config

Comment: it has 2 more nested inner exception one says "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.\r\n)"" and the other is null. @alisabzevari

Comment: Apparently your connection string is incorrect.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ContactMVC-20150620105152;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ContactMVC-20150620105152.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: how can I fix it ? @alisabzevari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix your connection. But incorrect connection string may have different causes. Try to connect to your database with Server Explorer in Visual Studio then select your database and press F4 (Properties). You can see the correct connection string there. Put it in connection string in your web.config.

Comment: Thanks, Solved the problem